# How do I compile boost for OS X 64b platforms with stdlibc++?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clang, libstdc++

I would like to compile boost for Mac OS X 10.9, with stdlibc++. I run the following command:

```
./b2 threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++"
```

The build completes successfully; however, my application build fails at linkage time, when it can't find symbols suck as std::__1::locale::use_facet, std::__1::basic_string etc. The pertinent detail there is the __1, I believe.

My question is, how do I compile boost for OSX 64b platforms with stdlibc++?

More info:

I have noticed the following logs during compilation:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/libboost_filesystem.a(windows_file_codecvt.o) has no symbols

Comment: You are compiling your application with `-stdlib=libstdc++`? because that will also be needed

Comment: @Petesh yes I'm compiling the app with libstdc++

Comment: Pick a boost library that you built which *definitely* relies on something in STL, run an nm on it, pipe it through `c++filt` and check that it's mentioning `std::__1::`. If it mentions that, then boost **has** been built with `libstdc++` and you're not compiling/linking your application properly in that case.

Comment: @Petesh if I perform those steps on libboost_filesystem.a I see the expected namespace. However I do notice in my compilation logs the following message >/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/libboost_filesystem.a(windows_file_codecvt.o) has no symbols

Comment: At a wild guess the .o file in question (with a name like windows_file_codecvt) is windows specific. It has a guard around the code: `#ifdef BOOST_WINDOWS_API`, so the lack of symbols in it is not unexpected

Comment: I had one of those colossal brain farts. Your boost is compiled with libc++, not libstdc++. I am losing my mind (apologies for the misdirection in this).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Downloaded Boost 1.55, bootstrapped using:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/boost155 cxxflags="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" \
    address-model=32_64 threading=multi macos-version=10.8 stage
```

Built using:

```
./b2 threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static \
    cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++"
```

Yields in `libboost_chrono.a`:

```
     U std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)
     U std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage
     U std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)
     U std::string::append(std::string const&)
     U std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)
     U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
     U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)
```

Which implies that the library was built with the option `-stdlib=libstdc++` - i.e. it's linked against the gnu version of the C++ runtime.

We purge the build using:

```
find . -name \*.o -print0 | xargs -0 rm
find . -name \*.a -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

If we don't do that then it doesn't rebuild, and you end up with the same code as before. Next we build using:

```
./b2 threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static \
    cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
```

Yields in `libboost_chrono.a`:

```
     U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*)
     U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)
     U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)
     U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
     U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
```

Which implies that it's built against `libc++`.

This can be verified by using a simple test c++ program (to indicate the linking):

```
#include <string>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s("Hello World");
    return 0;
}

$ make test
c++     test.cpp   -o test
$ nm ./test | c++filt
                 U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)
                 U std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()

$ rm test
$ make test CXXFLAGS=-stdlib=libstdc++
c++ -stdlib=libstdc++    test.cpp   -o test
$ nm ./test | c++filt
                 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
                 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
```

so yes, it's compiling with the relevant flag. What it does indicate that you have to pass the `-stdlib=libstdc++` to **everything** you're compiling if you're using XCode 5 as it now defaults to using `-stdlib=libc++`. This means that **any** C++ based libraries that depend on `c++` stdlib that you depend on also have to be compiled with the same flag.

Be careful with an *incremental* build of boost - if you don't purge the `.o` and `.a` files, they don't get recompiled based on the changed flags, which keeps the files as compiled, so if they were miscompiled then you encounter the problem.

Comment: Do you have ideas how it can be compiled under FreeBSD?
When I have tried to compile boost under FreeBSD with this command
`sudo ./b2 -j 4 threading=multi link=static toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++`, 
I have the following error
`libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp:15:10: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
#include <cstddef>`

Comment: You're compiling on a new release of FreeBSD (11.0?) that does not have a copy of `gcc` or `libstdc++` installed. You will first need to ensure that they have been installed on the system; then you *might* be able to build it. the FreeBSD project moved from `gcc` to `clang`, so in the long term, you're far better off building everything with clang, rather than trying to get this to work.

Comment: Petesh, thank you for a quick reply! Yes, I have FreeBDS 11.0 and  actually I have `gcc` installed and here is `locate` output :
`/usr/local/lib/gcc48/{libstdc++.a, libstdc++.so, libstdc++.so.6, libstdc++.so.6.0.19, libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py, libstdc++.a, libstdc++.so, libstdc++.so.6, libstdc++.so.6.0.20, libstdc++.so.6.0.20-gdb.py}
/usr/local/lib/gcc5/{libstdc++.a, libstdc++.so, libstdc++.so.6, libstdc++.so.6.0.21, libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py, libstdc++fs.a}
/usr/ports/lang/libstdc++_stldoc_4.2.2/{Makefile, distinfo, pkg-descr}`
What might be a problem in this case?

Comment: using `toolset=clang` with `-stdlib=libstdc++` won't work - it relies on clang being compiled with that support, and it isn't on FreeBSD. You'll have to bootstrap and build boost with gcc to get libstdc++ support - `./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc && ./b2 -j 4 threading=multi link=static`

Comment: I've built `b2` with `gcc` flag, but unfortunately still have an error: `gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/math/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/assoc_laguerre.o
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/math/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/assoc_laguerre.o...`
I use `gcc 5.4.0`

Comment: Looks to be an internal compiler error in relation to the precompiled header - probably compiler specific. as a potential workaround, do `rm bin.v2/libs/math/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/../src/tr1/pch.hpp.gch && touch bin.v2/libs/math/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/../src/tr1/pch.hpp.gch` and then rerun b2 - this nukes the precompiled header file, which *hopefully* will get you past the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've compiled boost and project with `clang` and `libc++`

Answer (score 0):

I use an easy command line to do the trick found on boost mailing list:
http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2014/02/81274.php

this is the snippet in case the link doesn't work anymore:

```
$ cd tools/build/v2/ 
$ ./bootstrap.sh 
$ cd ~/boost-stdc++-install/boost_1_54_0 
$ cd ~/boost-stdc++-install/boost_1_54_0 
$ tools/build/v2/b2 \ 
     --build-dir=`pwd`/tmp/build/ \ 
     --stagedir=`pwd`/tmp/stage/ \ 
     --buildid=libstdc++ \ 
     --layout=tagged -j24 \ 
     toolset=clang \ 
     cxxflags="-ftemplate-depth=999 -stdlib=libstdc++" \ 
     linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" \ 
     define=BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED stage
```