# Compile boost 1.57 for 64 bit with c++11 support for Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, boost

There are several similar topics:

[How do I compile boost for OS X 64b platforms with stdlibc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108407/how-do-i-compile-boost-for-os-x-64b-platforms-with-stdlibc)

[Linking troubles with boost::program_options on OSX using LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081818/linking-troubles-with-boostprogram-options-on-osx-using-llvm)

However, my problem still persists.

**What I want:**

- I want to compile on Mac OS X
- I compile my c++ programs with the following defines: **-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11  -m64**
- I want to link against the static (*.a) boost libraries, therefore I am trying to compile boost for 64 bit

**My last approach was:**

```
sudo sh bootstrap.sh address.model=64
```

Followed by

```
sudo ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" link=static install -j2
```

Everything compiles fine, however when I try to link against the boost-libraries I get several errors related to boost since the linker reports:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I tried several configurations, but the problem persists. I appreciate any help

Comment: Which symbols, specifically, are not found? Boost's symbols? Also, why are you building with `sudo`? That's generally discouraged.

Comment: Also, which version of OS X and Xcode do you have? Recent versions of Xcode don't even have libstdc++, so the `-stdlib=libc++` option is unnecessary.

Comment: It's been a while, but I thought Boost compiled into universal binaries on OS X, by default?

Comment: Can you augment your question with a dump of the symbols of some boost library that use stl? Something like `nm libboost_chrono.a | c++filt`. Please also provide more details of the compiler used to build your C++ programs (eg clang / clang++).