# How to uninstall Boost on mac?

Tags: macos, boost, uninstallation

I'm trying to build boost based on [this](https://github.com/alembic/alembic/blob/master/doc/Boost-howtobuild.txt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108407/how-do-i-compile-boost-for-os-x-64b-platforms-with-stdlibc) pages. After some trial and errors, it seems like some compiler flags I'm using might not make sense so I want to do a full uninstall of Boost first before reinstalling it again.

How can I go about doing it?

Comment: Instead of linking us github, provide code so we know where your problem is. What exactly have you tried. Flagging this as off topic since it doesn't seem like it's concretely about programming.

Comment: I'm new to building on mac. For now, suppose I'm completely following the second page to build Boost. Is there any way to remove it afterwards?

Answer (score 6):

It may be a bit late for a reply. What you basically need to do is to delete `/usr/local/lib/libboost*` and `/usr/local/include/boost` for a clean uninstallation. A reference is here: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/01/9444.php

For an easier installation of boost, you may want to consider using homebrew and just run `brew install boost`. For more installation options, you can check with `brew info boost`.

Comment: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies boost` works too